# followTouchMove not working on highcharts column chart, when using a mobile browser

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to add a column chart with a tooltip to our mobile app (android and iOS) inside a WebView

Because the issue happens also on the highcharts sample found on - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic
I won't add my html here.

When I open the html on a desktop browser, the mouse hover works fine, when i enter/exit a column, the right tooltip.formatter is triggered

but when i do the same with a mobile browser(or inside a WebView within my app) the scrolling only works if I start it outside a column.
If my finger starts the scroll by touching a column, the tooltip and the selected bar are stuck (every time i cross to a different column, the tooltip.formatter is triggered with the initial column i touched).

tested on safari, chrome and native android browser.
can you say what am i doing wrong?
should i add something to my script?

*using a simple column chart sample from highcharts site produces the same behavior
*changing to an other chart type solves this issue(i tried area,line, areaspline, spline)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
   type: 'column',
    animation: false,
    panning: false,
    pinchType: false,
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
  categories: [
  "24/10", "25/10", "26/10", "27/10", "28/10",
  "29/10", "30/10", "31/10", "1/11", "2/11",
  "3/11", "4/11", "5/11", "6/11", "7/11",
  "8/11", "9/11", "10/11", "11/11", "12/11",
  "13/11", "14/11", "15/11", "16/11", "17/11",
  "18/11", "19/11", "20/11", "21/11", "22/11",
  "23/11", "24/11", "25/11", "26/11", "27/11"
  ]
/*
  labels: {
  rotation: 290
        },
    //type: 'datetime',
    }*/
  },
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value.toLocaleString();
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },

  credits: {
    enabled: false,
    href: null

  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true,
    enabled: true,
    followTouchMove: true,
    followPointer: false,
    formatter: function() {

      var date = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m', new Date(this.points[0].key));
      var d = new Date();

      var x = 'x=';
      var y = 'y=';
     // d.setTime(this.points[0].key);
x = this.points[0].key;
      //x = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m', d); //
      y = (this.points[0].y).toString();
      document.getElementById('tooltip_date').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 125%;color:black;font-weight: regular">' + x + '</span>';
      document.getElementById('tooltip_value').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 125%;color:black;font-weight: bold">' + y + ' impressions.</span>';
      if(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % 2 == 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('tooltip_change').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 100%;color:green;font-weight: bold"> ▲ 27.5% (WoW)</span>';
            }
            else
            {
            document.getElementById('tooltip_change').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 100%;color:red;font-weight: bold"> ▼ 27.5% (WoW)</span>';
            }

      var lm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      var sheets = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
      var sqm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
      document.getElementById('tooltip_desc').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 90%;color:black;font-weight: regular"> lm: '+lm +'; sheets: '+ sheets+'; sqm: '+sqm+'</span>';



      return false;
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      //pointStart: Date.UTC(2017, 9, 24),
      //pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'print volume',
    animation: false,
    data: [200000, 203000, 30000, 125000, 100000, 232000, 123000, 340000, 90700, 195000, 92000, 223000, 130000, 75000, 165000, 108000, 130000, 237000, 165000, 148000, 228000, 163000, 210000, 127000, 125000, 109000, 143000, 127000, 15000, 105000],

  }]
});


function randomWholeNum() {

  // Only change code below this line.

  return Math.random();
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://highcharts.github.io/pattern-fill/pattern-fill.js"></script>

<style>
body {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="tooltip" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="tooltip_date">date</div>
    <div>
        <span id="tooltip_value">val </span> <span id="tooltip_change">change </span>
    </div>
    <div id="tooltip_desc">desc</div>
</div>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my sample html can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/htkmaugqdng91e5/sample_highcharts_column.html?dl=0

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue on my Android device (Chrome): https://ibb.co/gHQkfG You can see that sometimes the chart ignores the drag move - the tooltip remains in it's previous position. Is that the problem that you're facing?

Comment: Yes....looks like if you start the scroll outside of a column it works (sometimes) but if you start by touching a column it stays on it no matter where you move

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7484

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was sure I was doing something wrong